# Append/Prepend with onclick doesn't work (HELP PLS)

Tags: jquery

Many hours at this and nothing seems to work. Help please!

I need to insert these 3 sets of code:

CODE 1: `<div onclick="openClose('stp1')" style="cursor:hand; cursor:pointer">`

CODE 2: `</div><div id="stp1" class="texter">`

CODE 3: `</div>`

into this table:

```
<table id='options_table'>
<tr><td colspan=3><font size="3" class="colors_productname">
<i><b><font size=2>(NEED TO INSERT CODE 1 HERE) STEP 1: (NEED TO INSERT CODE 2 HERE)<font color=red>*</b></i>
</font>
<br /><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td><img src="/images/Line_Group_Features.gif" /></td></tr></table>
</font></td></tr>
<tr>
<td align="right" vAlign="top">
<img src="/images/clear1x1.gif" width="1" height="4" border="0"><br />
</td><td></td><td>

<br><br /></td></tr> (NEED TO INSERT CODE 3 HERE)
<tr><td colspan=3><font size="3" class="colors_productname">
<i><b><font size=2>STEP 2:</b></i>
</font>
<br /><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td><img src="/images/Line_Group_Features.gif" /></td></tr></table>
</font></td></tr>
<tr>
....
```

I've tried this:

```
$("img[src$='Line_Group_Features.gif']:eq(0)").closest('font').prepend('<div onclick="openClose(\'stp1\')" style="cursor:hand; cursor:pointer">');
$("img[src$='Line_Group_Features.gif']:eq(0)").closest('font').append('</div><div id="stp1" class="texter">');
$("img[src$='Line_Group_Features.gif']:eq(1)").prev('tr'):eq(.append('</div>');
```

and this:

```
$("img[src$='Line_Group_Features.gif']:eq(0)").closest('font').prepend('<div id="clickstp1" style="cursor:hand; cursor:pointer">');
$("img[src$='Line_Group_Features.gif']:eq(0)").closest('font').append('</div><div id="stp1" class="texter">');
$("img[src$='Line_Group_Features.gif']:eq(1)").closest('font').prepend('</div>');
$('#clickstp1').bind('click', function()) {  openClose('stp1');});
```

but nothing's working.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to do this:

```
$("img[src$='Line_Group_Features.gif']:eq(0)").before('<div onclick="openClose(\'stp1\')" style="cursor:hand; cursor:pointer">');
$("img[src$='Line_Group_Features.gif']:eq(0)").after('</div><div id="stp1" class="texter">');
```

Comment: shouldnt he be using `wrap` instead... wont before/after append/prepend append hi html as text nodes or botch the dom if he doesnt use complete nodes? also `font` is an html element.. or was, and it is in his example.

Comment: I saw the font afterwards (i missed it the first time). Wrap can work with some changes to his code. I tried to make the least changes to show him how to go from there. You are correct though that wrap is good. About dom botching, he should be okay if he does complete the elements.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this is going to work for you even if you get the insertion correct because:

1. im pretty sure `font` is an inline element and thus cant contain a block level element like `div`
2. `div` is not valid outside of a `td` or `th` in a `table`/`tbody`/`thead`.